# "Were you able to go to their office and have an on-site interview?" or "Were you able to go to their office and had an on-site interview?"

Tags: grammar, usage

In this context, should I use "have" or "had"? I am not really sure. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the constructions are correct. If you say

> Were you able to go to their office and have an on-site interview?

You can parse it as

> "Were you able to go to their office and able to have an on-site interview?
>
> (Were you able to go to their office) and ( you had an on-site interview)?